# python3 pip install does not install a module globally

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Suppose I start a docker container `from python:3.8-slim` and add a module:

```
foomod/
   __init__.py
   setup.py
   this.py
   that.py
```

And install it:

```
python3 -m pip install foomod
```

Well, as long as I am in the folder containing `foomod`, everything works.

However, as soon as I remove `foomod` (`rm -rf foomod`) or move to a different directory, `python3` no longer imports the directory.

How does one `pip install` the module such that it is genuinely installed? Is there some path or setting missing?

Comment: Wrong directory structure (`setup.py` must be one level higher). And we don't see said `setup.py` so we cannot help fixing it; please show it. Meanwhile please reread https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was not necessarily that `setup.py` can't install the package it is actually in, as in the following layout:

```
foobar/
   this.py
   that.py
   __init__.py
   requirements.txt
   setup.py
```

But rather that `setuptools.find_packages` finds directories recursively from the starting position it is called from.  So, **the fix is**:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
name = os.path.basename(cwd)
packages = setuptools.find_packages(exclude=["test*"]) + [name]
package_dir = { name: os.getcwd() }

# note that it is not correct to change directory to '../' since
# the user may have (like me) placed multiple packages side by side
# in the ancestor directory
```

Code up a solution with `os`.  Note that `os` is generally always a requirement in a `setup.py` script, so this did not introduce dramatic changes.

---

And **the reason why it is good**: it enables modularization in a standard python recursive build without introducing excessive intermediate directories:

```
libs/
  setup.py
  small_libA/ {Depends: numpy}
     __init__.py
     foo.py
     bar.py
     requirements.txt
     README.md

  small_libB/ {Depends: small_libA, pandas}
     __init__.py
     biz.py
     baz.py
     requirements.txt
     README.md

  small_libC/ {Depends: small_libA, small_libB, 750mb whatever }
```

Without this fix must become:

```
libs/
   setup.py
   small_libA/
      setup.py
      small_libA/
          __init__.py
          foo.py
          bar.py
      ...

# which has the irritating interface when installed from the 
# top position:
from all_libs_module import small_libA.small_libA.foo

# in addition to a 2x node-explosion in the source tree
```

But that with the fix, the following pattern can be implemented without the 2x nodular multiplier:

```
libs/
   setup.py {idiomatic setup.py with unmodified find_packages}
   small_libA/ 
      setup.py {modified setup.py for atomic lib installs}
      __init__.py
      foo.py
      bar.py
    ...
```

Where `__init__.py` contains logic necessary to ignore `setup.py, __init__.py, README.md, etc.`.

These features are great when putting a single library in a recursive structure in a dockerfile.  They also keep python simpler at the project level than C and C++ (which is the idea, right?).

And, it makes it possible to pinpoint functionality in a project via the `vcs` syntax:

```
python3 -m pip install git+https://repo@branch#egg=foo&subdirectory=libs/foobar/foo
```

Without losing the ability to install all python libs the same way:

```
python3 -m pip install git+https://repo@branch#egg=reponame&subdirectory=libs
```